# Stability of Nash equilibria in best response dynamics

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, game-theory, stability-in-odes, nash-equilibrium, fixed-points

If we define a Nash equilibrium as a fixed point of the best-response mapping, i.e. a strategy $x$ s.t.
$$x\in BR(x),$$
where BR denotes the (set-valued) best-response mapping, then
$$\dot x \in BR(x)-x$$
is generally referred to as best-response dynamics (BR dynamics).

I have two utility functions, $u_1(c,s)$ and $u_2(c,s)$. They are derivable. $u_1(c,s)$ refers to Player 1, while $u_2(c,s)$ to Player 2. The strategic leverage of Player 1 is $s$ while the strategic leverage of Player 2 is $c$.

In order to obtain the best response functions and Nash equilibria, I have to solve the system of the following two equations:
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial s}u_1(c,s)=0$$
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial c}u_2(c,s)=0$$
From this I obtain both best response functions, i.e.
$$s=f_1(c)$$
$$c=f_1(s)$$
Then the best response dynamics are,
\begin{align}
\dot{x} &= BR(x) - x \\
\begin{pmatrix}\dot{s} \\ \dot{c}\end{pmatrix} &= \begin{pmatrix} f_1(c) \\ f_2(s)\end{pmatrix} - \begin{pmatrix} s \\ c\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
I can replace the $\in$ with $=$ because the map $f_1, f_2$ are not set value maps but are single-valued.

Then I evaluated the Jacobian of this system in Nash equilibria (I have two equilibria and then two fixed points) in order to determine their stability. I found that they are both asymptotically stable because the eigenvalues of Jacobian have negative real parts.

I would like to know if this is due to a general result (e.g. BR dynamics have always asymptotically stable fixed points) or it might happen that (for another game) one equilibrium is stable and another not.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In a dynamic system there are stable and unstable equilibria. However, to study those one needs to solve in general the dynamic system numerically. The nature of an equilibrium can be changed due to a change in the model parameters, to capture this one has to study the model with the help of bifurcation theory. To get some understanding, I recommend to study Chapter 2 and the Appendix of my book:  https://www.springer.com/de/book/9783540432951.

Comment: Moreover, the following link might also be of interest: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/321777732_Applying_Lie_Group_Analysis_to_a_Dynamic_Resource_Management_Problem